# Pandas - Create column containing a list of all years between the start and end years existing in two other columns

Tags: python, pandas, range

Given this sample data:

```
    Claimant    Zan_start_yr  Zan_end_yr
0   Joe            1980        1985   
1   mary           1995        2001     
2   martha         2000        2002
```

I am trying to create a column containing a list of all the dates between the start and end dates of Zan inclusive.

I tried this among other things, keep getting various errors:

```
df['zan_yr_range_list'] = list(range(df['Zan_start_yr'].astype('int') , df['Zan_end_yr'].astype('int')))
```

TypeError: 'Series' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Ideal result would be this:

```
Claimant           Zan_start_yr Zan_end_yr    Zan_yr_range_list 
    0   Joe            1980        1985     [1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985] 
    1   mary           1995        2001     [1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001] 
    2   martha         2000        2002     [2000, 2001, 2002]
```

And my data is likely strings of the years that I would have to first convert to integers before creating this column of the years in a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do `zip`

```
df['zan_yr_range_list'] = [list(range(x,y)) for x , y in zip(df['Zan_start_yr'].astype('int'),df['Zan_end_yr'].astype('int'))]
```

Comment: Wow, @BEN_YO that was it.  I don't know why I missed the zip part.  I use zip here and there but it never occurred to me.  Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

You can also assign a series directly using list function.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Claimant': ['Joe','mary','martha'], 'Zan_start_yr': ['1980', '1995', '2000'],'Zan_end_yr': ['1985', '2001', '2002']})
df['Zan_yr_range_list'] = [list(range(i, j+1)) for i, j in df[['Zan_start_yr', 'Zan_end_yr']].astype(int).values]
```